# slf4j logging - Understanding the exception stacktrace for Exception logging

Tags: java, exception, logging, slf4j, error-logging

Using [slf4j 1.7.x](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/Logger.html) for logging in our Java project. I am publishing events to Kafka and using [kafka-clients 2.2.0](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients/2.2.0/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html).
In the code below I want to take some action when some specific exceptions are thrown in the [Callback](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients/2.2.0/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/Callback.html). One of the exceptions I am expecting is shown below in **Logs** which is for the **Code** I have below.

**Code:**

```
  kafkaProducer.send(
      new ProducerRecord<>(topicName, envelope.toEnvelopeString()),
      (meta, exception) -> {
        if (exception != null) { // Exception thrown in the Callback
          // Need to take some action here
          logger.error(
              "Exception thrown during processing. topicName={}, tid={}",
              topicName,
              tid,
              exception);
          ...
        }
      });
```

**Logs:**

```
2021-03-03 18:30:45.429 ERROR 4682 --- [         bus-17] c.i.m.c.e.i.GroupAppConnection        : Exception thrown during processing. topicName=abc, tid=1-603fd5d0-37bcd101247a904a1274e3ff
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ApiException: com.mycompany.app.exceptions.SchemaViolationException: com.mycompany.app.exceptions.AuthorizationException: com.mycompany.dataprotection.domain.item.DataProtectionAccessControlException: API key is not authorized to access the item, API policy ID: policy123, roles=[], folderRoles: []
Caused by: com.mycompany.app.exceptions.SchemaViolationException: com.mycompany.app.exceptions.AuthorizationException: com.mycompany.dataprotection.domain.item.DataProtectionAccessControlException: API key is not authorized to access the item, API policy ID: policy123, roles=[], folderRoles: []
    at com.mycompany.app.validation.validator.SchemaSerializingValidator.encryptFields(SchemaSerializingValidator.java:327) ~[app-core-1.5.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.mycompany.app.validation.validator.SchemaSerializingValidator.validateJson(SchemaSerializingValidator.java:171) ~[app-core-1.5.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.mycompany.app.validation.validator.SchemaSerializingValidator.validate(SchemaSerializingValidator.java:59) ~[app-core-1.5.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.mycompany.app.impl.SerializingMessageFormaterImpl.format(SerializingMessageFormaterImpl.java:41) ~[app-core-1.5.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.mycompany.app.kafka.serde.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:96) ~[app-kafka-1.5.0.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:60) ~[kafka-clients-2.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:878) ~[kafka-clients-2.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:840) ~[kafka-clients-2.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.mycompany.core.endpoint.groupapp.GroupAppConnection.publishToApp(GroupAppConnection.java:402) ~[endpoint-0.5.1108-mygitbranch-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
    at com.mycompany.core.endpoint.groupapp.GroupAppConnection.publish(GroupAppConnection.java:396) ~[endpoint-0.5.1108-mygitbranch-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
    at com.mycompany.core.endpoint.groupapp.GroupAppEndpoint.handle(GroupAppEndpoint.java:42) ~[endpoint-0.5.1108-mygitbranch-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at com.google.common.app.Subscriber.invokeSubscriberMethod(Subscriber.java:87) ~[guava-28.2-jre.jar!/:na]
    at com.google.common.app.Subscriber$1.run(Subscriber.java:72) ~[guava-28.2-jre.jar!/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: com.mycompany.app.exceptions.AuthorizationException: com.mycompany.dataprotection.domain.item.DataProtectionAccessControlException: API key is not authorized to access the item, API policy ID: policy123, roles=[], folderRoles: []
    at com.mycompany.app.cryptography.DataProtectionEncrypter.encrypt(DataProtectionEncrypter.java:107) ~[app-core-1.5.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.mycompany.app.cryptography.DataProtectionEncrypter.encrypt(DataProtectionEncrypter.java:33) ~[app-core-1.5.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.mycompany.app.validation.validator.SchemaSerializingValidator.encryptFields(SchemaSerializingValidator.java:318) ~[app-core-1.5.0.jar!/:na]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mycompany.dataprotection.domain.item.DataProtectionAccessControlException: API key is not authorized to access the item, API policy ID: policy123, roles=[], folderRoles: []
    at com.mycompany.dataprotection.service.rest.vkmsecrecy.VkmSecrecyRestErrorService.handleAccessDeniedException(VkmSecrecyRestErrorService.java:106) ~[dataprotection-sdk-3.65.7.jar!/:na]
    at com.mycompany.dataprotection.service.rest.vkmsecrecy.VkmSecrecyRestService.retrieveItem(VkmSecrecyRestService.java:511) ~[dataprotection-sdk-3.65.7.jar!/:na]
    at com.mycompany.dataprotection.domain.item.ItemRepository.renewSecretLatest(ItemRepository.java:697) ~[dataprotection-sdk-3.65.7.jar!/:na]
    at com.mycompany.dataprotection.domain.item.ItemRepository.getItem(ItemRepository.java:472) ~[dataprotection-sdk-3.65.7.jar!/:na]
    at com.mycompany.dataprotection.domain.item.SecretImpl.retrieve(SecretImpl.java:151) ~[dataprotection-sdk-3.65.7.jar!/:na]
    at com.mycompany.dataprotection.domain.item.KeyImpl.getAlgorithm(KeyImpl.java:308) ~[dataprotection-sdk-3.65.7.jar!/:na]
    at com.mycompany.app.cryptography.DataProtectionEncrypter.encrypt(DataProtectionEncrypter.java:91) ~[app-core-1.5.0.jar!/:na]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

**My question is:** Based on this stack trace, if I would like match for this particular exception should I be matching it as follows, if not how?

```
if (exception instanceof org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ApiException
    && exception.getCause() instanceof com.mycompany.app.exceptions.SchemaViolationException) {
  // Take the action here
}
```

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "this particular exception". The real exception is usually the deepest one, which is the **`DataProtectionAccessControlException`** with message `"API key is not authorized to access the item"`. That exception was then wrapped with 3 exceptions: `AuthorizationException`, `SchemaViolationException`, and `ApiException`, and maybe more. Since we can't see the full stacktrace, we don't know, but that is what the message of the topmost exception indicates.

Comment: Thanks Andreas, that makes perfect sense to me. So does the code, I mentioned to match the exception would work? Also if I would like to get the deepest exception, I can use apache commons lang `ExceptionUtils.getRootCause(ex) instanceof DataProtectionAccessControlException`, right? And How about checking for all the intermediate causes to match a specific one, would I have to loop through with `e.getCause()` and match with what I want to check for or is there some apache library method available for that too?

Comment: @Andreas I have also added full stacktrace for reference.

Comment: Or you could just compare the `toString()` values. As I said, it depends on what you mean by "this particular exception". Is the message *"API key is not authorized to access the item, API policy ID: policy123, roles=[], folderRoles: []"* part of that, or are you just after any `DataProtectionAccessControlException`? Normally I'd say that *"API key is not authorized"* is part of the exception "type", but *"policy ID: policy123"* is too detailed, identifying "data" but not classifying the exception. But that's all for you to decide.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. I am essentially looking for `ApiException: SchemaViolationException` or the root exception of type/subtype of `DataProtectionException`. Might as well check for the exception message too later on.

Comment: @Andreas, When you get a chance could you pls add your comments as an answer, so I could accept that. Or I can also put those as an answer, not an issue.